# Regexp - How to check whether a string starts OR ends with given character?

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

String that start AND ends with that character should not be a match.

Is it just easiest to do something like:

```
$string = '!test';
preg_match('/^(!?)([a-z0-9]{1,10})(!?)$/i', $string, $matches);
```

and examine $matches?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the requirements? `!test` starts with `!` and ends in `t`, so it should match? Aren't `substr($string, 0, 1)` and `substr($string, -1)` enough? Could you provide 2 sample inputs, 1 valid and 1 invalid?

Comment: @stribizhev I am testing the characters in the middle as well, so I need regexp. In this example the "given character" is '!'. I want to check whether a string starts OR ends with '!'.

Comment: Please explain what you want to match in total, including the in-between stuff. In words.

Comment: @simbabque I need to check whether a string is 1 to 10 chars long, contains only alphanumerics and optionally ends OR starts with an exclamation mark.

Comment: @simbabque Thanks, your updated answer is exactly what I need, I thought there is more elegant way but speed is more important in this particular case.

Comment: Depends what you call elegant. The most elegant solution to me is the one that produces the smallest number of **WTF**s in a code review and makes the next guy not waste half an hour trying to understand what the code is supposed to mean. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just have one character at the beginning or the end, it's as simple as saying this:

```
/^!|!$/
```

No need for a capture group.

---

**Update:** To make sure you get either *an exclamation mark and ten letters* or *ten letters and an exclamation mark*, build your pattern like this:

```
/^!?[a-z0-9]{1,10}$|^[a-z0-9]{1,10}!?$/
```

It looks like it's repeating itself, but it's actually way cheaper and faster than having three capture groups.

I put together [a unit test in regex101 for this](https://regex101.com/r/uH1fQ2/2).

Comment: Thanks, but I need to test the characters in between too. Doing this at the moment: `!preg_match('/^(!?)([a-z0-9]{1,10})(!?)$/i', $code, $matches) || ($matches[1] && $matches[3])`

Comment: Don't try to build a complicated regular expression. Just write several lines of code. That's way easier to maintain.